# Can Google Index Rewriten URLs?

Tags: seo, google, url-rewriting, download

Can Google index rewriten URLs? I mean, if I have the link

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/document">Grab the document!</a>
```

and if I instruct Apache to rewrite `http://mydomain.com/document` as `http://mydomain.com/document.pdf` or `http://mydomain.com/download.php?file=document.pdf`, will Google still be able to index the contents of the resulting PDF file?

Answer (score 5):

Google sees the URL you publish. The rewrite happens in the background and is invisible to them. So as long as your URL is valid and the content you want can be reached with it Google will index it just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will people, in this case, still be able to use the "filetype:pdf" switch to search for this particular document?

Comment: Yes since that URL will ultimately return a PDF.